# Is it feasible to forge multiple, smaller parts in the same forging operation?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, forging

Let us assume you have a large forging press or drophammer, and drawings for a set of smaller parts that all need to be forged from the same material.  Would it be feasible to construct a forging die so that all the parts could be forged from a single billet and then separated as a machining step?  Or is this more expensive than making a forging die for each part and forging them separately from individual, smaller billets?

For the purposes of this question, you can assume that the parts all have a linear geometry -- say, if you wanted to forge a crankshaft and camshaft set for an engine in a single operation.

Comment: Voting to close as to broad, the question is not answerable without details of the parts in question. Specifically, cost is difficult to determine without an in-depth understanding of the part geometries. Feasibility of forging in general also depends on desired output geometry.

Comment: @starrise -- I gave an example set of output geometries that should do the trick; let me know if you need more information.

Comment: That is a much easier to answer question that I am unfortunately unequipped to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've previously worked in the forging industry and you can certainly forge multiple parts in a single stroke of a large press but there are problems.   The obvious ones are the size of the available press and the economics of the operation.   However, even from a metallurgical point of view, forging a complex part like a crankshaft in one stroke would induce more plastic deformation than the material could take, at least at room temperature.   The shaft would then have to be hot-forged to maintain the ductility of the material during deformation and the temperature required is critical.   I can't imagine that you could do a crankshaft and a camshaft at the same time.   And apart from that, complex parts are usually forged in stages, each stage taking the component closer to its final shape.   Again, I can't see this being done for a crankshaft and a camshaft in a single die.

But I could be out-of-date...

Comment: Yeah, the crankshaft/camshaft example was simply a set of geometries that'd be familiar to folks here.  (I was envisioning a hot-forging process anyway, too)